# Catch an exception from an instance created with Activator.CreateInstance(type)

Tags: c#, plugins, exception

I have a C# application that can load other dlls with Activator.CreateInstance(type), that implement a given interface (plugins).

Now I want to catch all exceptions thrown from that new instance in it's own exception handler (because I cannot be sure that every exception is handled by the plugin properly) to present a message like:

> Plugin [PluginName] caused the following error: [Exception.Message]

I can subscribe to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event, but this catches all exceptions and not only the ones caused by a certain plugin and I also can't see [that the|what] plugin caused the exception.

Is it possible to assign a exception handler to the created instance?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your exact scenario, but a solution could be creating a wrapper class around the plugin object that takes care of making sure all potential exceptions are handled correctly:

```
 public interface IPluginObject
 {
      void Foo();
      IBlah Bar();
      ...
 }

 public Wrapper<T>: IPluginObject where T: IPluginObject
 {
      private readonly T inner;

      public Wrapper(IPlugin obj) { inner = obj; }

      public void Foo()
      {
           try { inner.Foo() }
           catch ....
           finally ...
      }

      public IBlah Bar()
      {
           try { return inner.Bar(); }
           catch ...
           finally ...
      }
 }
```

Cumbersome? Yes, but you *do* get the benefit of knowing exactly what plugin is being troublesome.

Comment: You understood my scenario pretty exactly! But there might also be exeptions in methods of the plugin that are not called directly from the Plugincontainer. F.e. all plugins have to provide a UserControl that is displayed in a ContentControl of the main program. And in this UsreControl can be any sort of method calls that are unknown to the main program

Comment: @Aaginor oh, in that case this won't do, no.